# SwiftUI navigationBarTitle - displayMode: .inline - Crash

Tags: navigationbar, swiftui, ios13

I have a problem with SwiftUI. I am creating a list with a navigation bar, and I want to set navigation bar mode to inline, I don't want it to be large which is by default. But when I set navigation bar title mode to inline, the app crashes.

```
struct User {
    var index: Int
    var name: String
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var users: [User] = [
        User(index: 0, name: "Peter"),
        User(index: 1, name: "Marko"),
        User(index: 2, name: "John")]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(users.identified(by: \.index)) {
                UserRow(user: $0)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Users"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct UserRow: View {
    var user: User
    var body: some View {
        Text(user.name)
    }
}
```

I suppose that it is a SwiftUI bug.

Does someone know what could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above code is working fine. perhaps some other issues might affect a crash.
Which XCode Beta version you use?

Comment: I've tried with beta 1 and the latest beta 4. It crashes all the time. 

Maybe the problem is because I'm testing on simulator.

The app crashes in line: window.makeKeyAndVisible()

I get the error:
"nw_endpoint_get_type called with null endpoint
...
__nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash already simulated nw_endpoint_get_type called with null endpoint
..."
Some other people also have reported similar problem:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120104

Comment: I think that it is a problem with: UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false. When I remove this line, the code doesn't crash any more.

Comment: There are also some bugs in new XCode beta. Obviously, this code is Ok, but we are waiting for new XCode versions

Comment: This still happens even after XCode 11 was officially released. Not sure if it would work on a barebones SwiftUI-app, but our case does not where we have UIHostingController wrapping the SwiftUI view(s).

Comment: I have the same problem since I added UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

Comment: Seem like Swift UI bug, `UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false` ,  `navigationBarTitle - displayMode: .inline` and `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` combination made crash for me.
I gonna remove `UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false` for now to solve

Comment: @VladimirDinic how did you end up fixing it? I'm having users crashing due to this bug when they run 13.2 or 13.3

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is fixed in Xcode 11.4 beta 2