# navigationBarTitle / displayMode is crashing on iOS 13.2 and 13.3

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When loading this view, the app crashes on iOS 13.2 and 13.3 with an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error:

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                // Some content
            }.navigationBarTitle(
                    Text("home.title"),
                    displayMode: .inline
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Removing the `navigationBarTitle` part entirely, or just the `displayMode` will prevent the app from crashing. This looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57108069/swiftui-navigationbartitle-displaymode-inline-crash), but just upgrading xcode doesn't fix the problem.

Another interesting thing to note is that if I remove this line in my `ContentView`'s `init()` it does not crash:

```swift
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

It is fixed in later versions of iOS 13 and iOS 14, but I have users on older versions of iOS complaining. Do you have any idea of what the problem could be ?